# Insert quiz json data by clicking on "submit" button to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, insert

For a schoolproject i need to make an Quiz with json data + a scoreboard. 
The questions are retrieved via the json data and can be seen on my page. but as soon as you have answered the multiple choice questions and press the finish line (to view your score) then nothing happens. Below you see the code that I used.

So I want, as soon as I have clicked on the submit button, that I go to my score.php and that my score will be stored in the database that I have already connected to score.php

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submitscore'])) {                   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "root";         
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$session_score = $_POST['sessionscore'];
$sqlTwo = "INSERT INTO quiz_scores (session_id, session_date, session_score) VALUES ('".$_POST["session_id"]."','".$_POST["session_date"]."','".$_POST["session_score"]."')";

if ($conn->query($sqlTwo) === TRUE) 
  {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "Error"; } }?>      <!-- Submit knop -->   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  id="submitscore"> Submit</button>
```

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML form code as well

Comment: okay thankyou but do you know a solution for this problem :D?

Comment: No. Not enough information. All we can do with this is make guesses

Comment: To ask On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: with the limited information you're giving, one thing is rather obvious, your `if (isset($_POST['submitscore']))` will never fire, because it doesn't exist. You have an `id='submitscore'`, but that won't work. You need to set `name='submitscore'` in your form for it to end up in your $_POST array. So I'd suggest you code a small form, along the lines of `<form method='post'> <button ... name='submitscore'></form>` and it should work.

Comment: @lovelace thankyou for your answer. i placed the form <form method='post'><button class="btn btn-info" name='submitscore' id='submitscore'> subtmit</form>  . But now i get Notice: Undefined variable: session_score in on line 99